Do we have too many unanswered questions?
25 open questions with no answer with an upvote or acceptance.
Should we try harder to answer these questions? Or is it normal for the community at this stage?

Having 96% of your questions answered is commendable, but nobody likes to see questions unanswered. It provides a bad experience for the author and anyone who finds this site seeking the information.
So, yes, that is always a good place to put a bit of extra effort; to get those unanswered questions answered.

Well, seeing that our answer ratio is 2.2, whereas 2.5+ is a desired ratio, giving more answers in general is useful. The open questions in particular are a good place to start, as any additional input would be appreciated by the authors of the questions.
